# How to get direction from onDragUpdate

Tags: flame

How would you get a direction from onDragUpdate?

```
  Vector2 dragDeltaPosition = Vector2(0, 0);
  Vector2 dragDirectionVector = Vector2(0, 0);

  @override
  bool onDragStart(DragStartInfo info) {
    dragDeltaPosition = info.eventPosition.game - position;
    return false;
  }

  @override
  bool onDragUpdate(DragUpdateInfo info) {
    // double x = info.eventPosition.game.x - dragDeltaPosition.x;
    // double y = info.eventPosition.game.y - dragDeltaPosition.y;

    // double x = info.eventPosition.game.x - info.delta.game.x;
    // double y = info.eventPosition.game.y - info.delta.game.y;

    dragDirectionVector = Vector2(x, y);
  }
```

Update: this kind of work:

```
double x = (info.eventPosition.game - position).x - dragDeltaPosition.x;
double y = (info.eventPosition.game - position).y - dragDeltaPosition.y;
```

Let me know if there is a better way. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to look on the `delta`, which is the vector from the last `onDragUpdate` to the current one.

```dart
  @override
  bool onDragUpdate(DragUpdateInfo info) {
    // You can use info.delta.game.normalized here too if you don't care
    // about the length of the directional vector.
    dragDirectionVector = info.delta.game;
  }
```